# ss command output explanation

Tags: linux

While running `ss -m` command, which shows the memory usage of a socket. I got the following output.

```
ESTAB  0  0   172.16.31.158:55266    115.114.106.17:imap2    mem:(r0,w0,f0,t0)
```

Can someone please explain me what these four character 'r' 'w' 'f' 't' denotes here?

Comment: I'm no expert, but this seems to have come before here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33855/kernel-socket-structure-and-tcp-diag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this excellent question and answer over on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33855/kernel-socket-structure-and-tcp-diag):

`r` represents the read (inbound) buffer
`w` represents the write (outbound) buffer
`f` represents the "forward allocated memory" (memory available to the socket)
`t` represents the transmit queue (stuff waiting to be sent or waiting on an `ACK`)

There is more detail (and some great reference resources) on the [unix.se question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33855/kernel-socket-structure-and-tcp-diag).